# Customize D3.js tween transition intervals

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm trying to create a D3.js animation where circles on map become visible according to the chronological order of timestamp data associated with each circle. The D3 tween method was the approach I implemented, specifically, [attrTween](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#attrTween). However, the intervals that the attrTween function steps through as it transitions from the start value to the end value are too few for my application, which leads to a jarring effect as large numbers of circles appear with each step in the transition rather than just a small number of circles if the interval was smaller.

The code relevant to the transition is shown below:

```
        selection.transition()
        .duration(20000)
        .ease("linear")
        .attrTween("visibility",function(d, i, a){
            return function(t) {
                if (d.timestamp <= dateInterpolate(t)) {
                    return "visible" ;
                } else {
                    return "hidden" ;
                }
            }
        })
```

How could the intervals which the attrTween method steps through be adjusted to allow for a smoother transition? Or is there an alternative approach that's more suited for this application?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. In general, the limit for the "intervals" of a transition is how fast the browser can render. Maybe you need to increase the duration of the transition?

Comment: You're right - the browser's rendering speed dynamically affects the time between intervals of the transition. I reduced the computation time required for each iteration within the tween transition, and animation achieved the desired smoothness. Thanks for your help!